# Google Analytics Crash reports and iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, google-analytics, crash-reports

Why I can see crash reports in Google Analytics but in iTunesConnect the page of crash reports is empty? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunesConnect uses an OS level handler that doesn't capture exceptions the same way Google Analytics, Crittercism, BugSense and other Error Monitoring solutions capture exceptions. As a result it misses many exceptions.

Unfortunately I don't have the specifics of how this works.